# How to find out if the following SQL statement is working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to mysql and I was wondering if the following code should be working. I've been checking with my database after submission of this form and nothing is getting inputted into the database. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, Thank you!

```
 <?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];


        if( strlen($username) > 0 && strlen($email) > 0 && strlen($desc) > 0)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO feature_request_table (username, desc, email, url, priority, status)
            VALUES( '$username' , '$desc' , '$email' , '$url' , '$priority' , '0' )";
            echo "The sql statement is: " . $sql . "</br>";
            mysql_query($sql);  
            //echo "The result is: " . $results . "</br>";  
            echo "Your request have been sent. Please allow a brief period of time for your webmaster implement your request. Thank you!";
        }


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `echo mysql_error();`.  Also, check your mysql log.

Comment: Can you run the sql statement on PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Please read up on SQL injection vulnerabilities.  Your script is vulnerable as it currently is to database tampering and hacking.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection  In short, you should call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on ALL of the variables you use in your SQL query.

Comment: Example: `$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the return value of `mysql_query()` and check if it is `NULL` to find out if the query was successful:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// A NULL value of $result indicates failure
if (!$result) {
  // something went wrong!

  // See the error...
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

Also, we don't see in the posted code that `mysql_connect()` was called.  Also check that the connection was successfully made:

```
$conn = mysql_connect(all the connection details...);
if (!$conn) {
  // connection failed
}
```

Comment: Okay so I did what you said and it says: 
The sql statement is: INSERT INTO feature_request_table (username, desc, email, url, priority, status) VALUES( 'scsper' , 'test123' , 'scsper@gmail.com' , '123' , '1' , '0' )
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, email, url, priority, status) VALUES( 'scsper' , 'test123' , 'scsper@g' at line 17

Comment: @KyleL  `desc` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, used for specifying descending order in the `ORDER BY` clause, but you are also using it as a column name.  To avoid that error, you'll need to refer to your `desc` column enclosed in backticks like \`desc\`

Comment: @KyleL  99.9% of the time, the error in a SQL statement occurs immediately after the "`right syntax to use near '` part of the error message.

Comment: Also, I am calling mysql_connect in a seperate script. The connection was successfully made

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the `isset()` function instead of strlen. Also, it does look like your never actually connecting to a mysql server according to the given code. Try posting the sql statement that is echoed into phpMyAdmin directly.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I haven't seen mentioned yet is that you may not have auto-commit turned on, in which case your insert will return TRUE, but you will not see any change in the DB until you commit the insert.

Answer (score 0):

This sould do it :

```
$data = mysql_query($sql);

if($data === false) { // TODO: better error handling

// Do something...

  echo mysql_error();

// Or see the errors...

}
```

Note : if you want to have valid HTML pages in all situations handle your errors don't use **OR DIE()**.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the changes you need to do.

- Use the column name desc with some other name of enclose in 'desc'.
- Always print the error message or even terminate the output.
- Check whether the POST Items are received correctly or not.

Here is the modified code.

```
if( isset($username) && isset($email)  && isset($desc) )
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO feature_request_table (username, 'desc', email, url, priority, status)
            VALUES( '$username' , '$desc' , '$email' , '$url' , '$priority' , '0' )";
            echo "The sql statement is: " . $sql . "</br>";
            mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());  
            //echo "The result is: " . $results . "</br>";  
            echo "Your request have been sent. Please allow a brief period of time for your webmaster implement your request. Thank you!";
        }
```